# Strange behavior when initializing template structure

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

I have a structure:

```
template < class L, class R > struct X {
  X()
  { }

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, X& __x)
  {
    return str << '(' << __x.__val1 << ", " << __x.__val2 << ')';
  }

private:
  L __val1;
  R __val2;
};
```

and create it without initializing anything:

```
  X<std::size_t, std::string> x;
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

It always gives output: `(2, )`

But, when i do:

```
  X<std::string, std::size_t> x;
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

I have "right" behaviour with uninitialized variable: `(, 94690864442656)`.

Why?

Comment: names with double underscores are reserved. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers

Comment: I think we should have a sign with huge red letters whenever someone asks a question in C++, saying "Undefined Behaviour is undefined". And yes, getting consistent outputs on every run still matches the definition of "undefined".

Comment: what output other than `(2, )` did you expect? And whats the difference between the first and the second snippet?

Answer (score 3):

There is no "right" value of an uninitialized variable.

The value is said to be "indeterminate". Using an indeterminate value leads to undefined behavior. Your program could output anything or nothing.

Assuming `(, 94690864442656)` to be "right", because it looks like some "uninitialized value" while `(2, )` looks like something was initialized, is wrong.

`2` is just as wrong as `94690864442656`. When the behavior of your code is undefined, then it is undefined.

---

If it helps, think of it like this: You are supposed to calculate the result of `2*3`. Instead of actually carrying out the calculation you call the number that comes to your mind in that moment. Most of the time you will say the wrong result. Once in a while you will answer with a result that looks meaningful, because you correctly guessed `6`, or you said `5` or `7` which is just off by one. However, getting the expected result sometimes, does not imply that your way of getting the result is correct.

Or consider this: (but be careful with the use of randomness here. Uninitialized values are not random!) Suppose instead of calculating the result of `2*3` you use the wrong way of rolling a dice (instead of actually calculating the number). Now assume you roll a `6`. Would you be surprised to get the "correct" result, even though your algorithm is wrong?

---

If you really care why you get `2` in one case and `94690864442656` in the other, you need to study the assembly generated by the compiler, because C++ does not specify what is the outcome of compiling code with undefined behavior. It just says: It is undefined.

---

Note that also using identifiers that contain a double underscore is not allowed, as such names are reserved (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers).